# How to handle multiple form pages with dojo.style?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, hide, show

I am using dojo 1.6 and trying to handle form pages with the following code :

```
dojo.forEach(dojo.query(".form-page"), function(page, i){
    if(page.id == "form-part1"){
        dojo.style(page, "display", "block");
    }else{
        dojo.style(page, "display", "none");
    }
 });

 dojo.query(".nextPgButton").connect("onclick", function(){
      var pages = dojo.query(".form-page");
      dojo.forEach(pages, function (page, i){
          if(dojo.style(page, "display") != "none"){
               dojo.style(page, "display", "none");
               dojo.style(page[i+1], "display", "block");
           }
      });
 });
```

The first statement works as only the first page is diplayed as expected. But the second doesn't retrieve the current style of the page correctly. So when I click on my next page button, all pages are hidden.

```
dojo.style(page,"display") // always return "block"
```

Can someone tell me why dojo.style doesn't retrieve the actual style of my page ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some really weird stuff there.

Your last line with `page[i+1]` will actually never work since `page` is not an array. I suppose you probably meant `pages[i+1]`.

If you actually meant what I just said, then it's common sense that it will return `block`. Just consider the case where you have two `.form-page` elements. When clicking your button the following happens:

**First iteration**:
Your first element with ID `#form-part1` has `display: block` because you set it that way initially. This obviously means the `if()` statement inside the `forEach()` is being executed since it's not equal to `"none"`.

This means that it sets the style of `#form-part1` to `display: none`, but it also means it sets the next element CSS to `display: block`.

**Second iteration**:
Your second `.form-page` now has `display: block` (read the last sentence of the previous iteration). This means the `if()` is **also** executed, setting the style back to `display: none`.

It will also try to find the next page, but there are no other pages anymore so it will also throw an error (another fault in your code).

---

So you obviously have to recheck your code since you're doing some thing(s) wrong. You will also have to rephrase your question because right now it's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve. But to me it makes sense that if you're having 2 pages, the `if()` statement is always being executed.

Comment: Thanks, i did mean "pages[i+1]", just a copy error. Indeed, it is now clear. I have just edited my code and it works. I used dojo.some instead of dojo.forEach to exit the loop.